Vim visual block copy don't paste in KDE konsole
Selecting by visual line mode and copying (V and y) in vim in rxvt-unicode or in gnome-terminal and pasting in another tab of that terminal with Shift + Insert works well.
But trying to do the same with konsole (KDE) does not work. The only thing which works is using mouse selecting and pasting or mouse selecting and Ctrl + Shift + v but that's not that effective.
No SSH / tmux / screen used, just plain terminal.
I can reproduce exactly the same behavior on different Linux distributions, using the same config (~/.vimrc and ~/.vim/).

Welcome to [vi.se]!

V doesn't put you in visual-block mode, it puts you in visual-line mode. Do <C-v> for visual-block mode. Also, are you using the same Vim with the same config on the same machine in both cases? Is SSH or Tmux involved?

Again: is this the same Vim, on the same machine?

@romainl Yes, it's the same Vim, on the same machine (and reproduced on two systems, i.e. twice).

Use Vim's or Konsole's issue tracker.

It looks like this has been reported 11 years ago: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=315583. It does not look anybody was interested to fix this.

Well, there you are. I think this question can be deleted.

There is feature request from 2013, not implemented
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=315583
I wonder if I'm first who is using vim in konsole this way (feature missing by many people would have been implemented).

"feature missing by many people would have been implemented" That's not how open source works at all. Moreover, with you that's 5 users known to be affected by that problem, which is hardly "many people", and there is an easy workaround anyway.

I guess you mean to use gvim. Well, instead I try to use a different terminal emulator.

Not "to use gvim", to install gvim.

Ah, you talk about +X11 support (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=315583#c2). I have that on both systems where I reproduce the problem. Maybe I'm missing some configuration.
